# Windows application - Fill textboxes/datetimepicker using dropdownlist

Tags: c#, database, windows, drop-down-menu

Good day everyone.

I want to fill my textboxes and etc in my windows app using my dropdownlist which is connected to my database. I've been googling around and all I get back are ASP.NET results which leaves me confused. I'd appriciate it if someone can help me to the right direction. I'm still new to programming so my code might look messy and maybe not even make sense to some of you. But it works so far :P

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ExamenIliasBelHaj
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Database connectie
    SqlConnection Tickets = new SqlConnection("Data                        Source=MOCHINO\\EINDEXAMEN;Initial Catalog=Ticket;Integrated Security=True");

    //Variabelen voor combobox
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataTable table;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Dropdownlist
        string query = "SELECT Email, MelderID FROM Melder";
        fillCombo(zoekincidentCb, query, "MelderID", "Email");

    }

    private void opslaanBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //Dit is voor Table Probleem
        SqlCommand a = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO Probleem(MeldingTitel,         Probleem, Handeling, Opgelost, BoekA, BoekB, BoekC, BoekD, Opdrachten,   Melddatum, Einddatum) Values (@MeldingTitel, @Probleem, @Handeling, @Opgelost,   @BoekA, @BoekB, @BoekC, @BoekD, @Opdrachten, @Melddatum, @Einddatum)", Tickets);

         // a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProbleemID", idTxt.Text);
            a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeldingTitel",   meldingtitelTxt.Text);
            a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Probleem", probleemTxt.Text);
            a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Handeling", handelingTxt.Text);
            a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Opgelost", opgelostCb.SelectedItem);
            a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoekA", boekaCb.Checked);
            a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoekB", boekbCb.Checked);
            a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoekC", boekcCb.Checked);
            a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoekD", boekdCb.Checked);
            a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Opdrachten", opdrachtenTxt.Text);
            a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Melddatum", dtpStart.Value);
            a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Einddatum", dtpEind.Value);


           //Dit is voor Table Melder

            SqlCommand b = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO Melder(Email, voornaam, achternaam) Values (@Email, @voornaam, @achternaam)", Tickets);
            b.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailTxt.Text);
            b.Parameters.AddWithValue("@voornaam", vnaamTxt.Text);
            b.Parameters.AddWithValue("@achternaam", anaamTxt.Text);

            Tickets.Open();
            a.ExecuteNonQuery();
            b.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Tickets.Close();

            emailTxt.Text = "";
            vnaamTxt.Text = "";
            anaamTxt.Text = "";
            meldingtitelTxt.Text = "";
            probleemTxt.Text = "";
            handelingTxt.Text = "";
            opdrachtenTxt.Text = "";
            boekaCb.Checked = false;
            boekbCb.Checked = false;
            boekcCb.Checked = false;
            boekdCb.Checked = false;
            opgelostCb.Items.Clear();                     
    }
```

In my fillCombo I have the following.

```
       public void fillCombo(ComboBox combo, string query, string displayMember, string valueMember)
    {
        command = new SqlCommand(query, Tickets);
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        combo.DataSource = table;
        combo.DisplayMember = "ProbleemID";
        combo.ValueMember = valueMember;

    }
```

This is what I've got based on the answer.

```
  private void zoekachternaamCb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("Select * from Melder, Probleem")
        vnaamTxt.Text = "voornaam";
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual issue you are encountering while trying to do this? There isn't a clear question apparent to me.

Comment: Elaborate what you need, Are you looking to populate textBox on Dropdownlist events?

Comment: My apologies. Basically my question is how I can fill up my textboxes with data stored in my database when I click on a certain item in my dropdownlist.

Comment: So what do you have in `fillCombo`?

Comment: Edited my post about the fillCombo, honestly I don't why it's up there. My programming teacher kind of forced me to use this.

Comment: You need to add more information or your vote will be closed. You reference text boxes, but your code doesn't have any. Please try and make an honest attempt at solving this and reducing it down to the exact piece of code that is confusing you.

Comment: Don't get me wrong I am really taking a honest attempt at solving this. The thing is I have no codes in my textboxes at all. I really do not have a clue what I should code in there. I was hoping that someone could just give me a push in the right direction as what kind of method I could use for this. I'm not looking for codes I can simply copy and paste I just need a push in the right direction so I can figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your query on

```
  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          string query = "SELECT Name, DateofBirth FROM TableName Where ID ="+comboBox1.Text;

    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conSTR);
    sqlConn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
    SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

   textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
   datePicker1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["DateOfBirth"].ToString(); 


    }
```

Comment: Yes! This worked for me, finally made some progress. Thank you for not giving up on me!